# How to disable swiping fancybox slides by mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I'm using **fancybox 3**. I need to turn off swiping fancybox slides by mousemove. I would like to leave only control buttons next\prev. 
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply set `touch:false` to disable touch events.

Answer (score 13):

So, the full answer will be:

Using **data-options** attribute

```
<a data-options='{"touch" : false}' data-fancybox data-src="#myElement" href="javascript:;">Click me</a>
```

Or when initializing fancybox

```
$('selector').fancybox({
    touch: false
});
```

From [@Janis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486595/janis) answer here: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1277

Comment: btw, a quick shortcut `data-touch='false'` works, too

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer did not work for me on Fancybox 3.5.*. I had to move the touch option to inside the opts object, like as follows:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    src: yoursource,
    opts: {
        touch: false
    }
});
```